# Cubic equation gets high loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to learn some machine learning and after looking up some tutorials I managed to train a linear regression and second degree equation with acceptable precision. I then decided to step it up a notch and try with: `y = x^3 + 9x^2` .

Since now everything worked fine, but with this new set my loss remains above 100k all the time and predictions are off by about `+-100`.

Here is a list of the things i tried:

- Increase number or layers
- Increase number of neurons
- Increase number of layers and neurons
- Vary batch size
- Increase and decrease learning rate
- Divided the number of epochs by 3 and trained him 3 times while feeding him a random data set each time
- Remove the kernel_regularizer (still have to understand what this does)

None of this solutions worked, each time loss was above 100k. Moreover I noticed that it's not a steady decrease, the resulting loss looks pretty random going from 100k to 800k and down again to 400k and then up to 1 million and down again....you can only notice that the average loss is going down but it's still hard to tell in that randomness

Some examples:

```
Epoch 832/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 757260.0625 - val_loss: 624795.0000
Epoch 833/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 784539.6250 - val_loss: 257286.3906
Epoch 834/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 481110.4688 - val_loss: 246353.5469
Epoch 835/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 383954.2812 - val_loss: 508324.5312
Epoch 836/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 516217.7188 - val_loss: 543258.3750
Epoch 837/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1042559.3125 - val_loss: 1702137.1250
Epoch 838/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 3192045.2500 - val_loss: 1154483.5000
Epoch 839/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1195508.7500 - val_loss: 4658847.0000
Epoch 840/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1251505.8750 - val_loss: 275300.7188
Epoch 841/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 294105.2188 - val_loss: 330317.0000
Epoch 842/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 528083.4375 - val_loss: 4624526.0000
Epoch 843/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 3371695.2500 - val_loss: 2008547.0000
Epoch 844/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 723132.8125 - val_loss: 884099.5625
Epoch 845/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 635335.8750 - val_loss: 372132.1562
Epoch 846/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 424794.2812 - val_loss: 349575.8438
Epoch 847/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 266175.3125 - val_loss: 247624.6719
Epoch 848/10000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 387106.7500 - val_loss: 1091736.7500
```

This was my original (and cleaner) code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from time import sleep

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu', input_shape=[1], kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
                             keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
                             keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
                             keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001)),
                             keras.layers.Dense(units=1)])

lr = 1e-1
decay = lr/10000

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, decay=decay)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

xs = np.random.random((10000, 1)) * 100 - 50;
ys = xs**3 + 9*xs**2 


model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=10000, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2)

print(model.predict([10.0]))

resp = input('Want to save model? y/n: ')
if resp == 'y':
    model.save('zig-zag')
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542824/learning-a-cubic-equation) question where the reported solution would be to use relu, but I already had that implemented and copying the code didn't work either.

Am I missing something? What and why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: @desertnaut doesn't this count as a bug? There's something wrong with my code and i'm asking about that

Comment: I am afraid not; it is not about *programming* (i.e. you don't get an error or something), it is about modeling *methodology*, which is off-topic here, as explained in the link. We have no less than 3 (!) dedicated SE sites for such questions.

Comment: @desertnaut not going to complain, i'm taking my question elsewhere if the answer provides no solution. I'm going to say that I disagree with this decision though: just because I didn't get an error this doesn't mean that is not programming related, there are plenty of (open) similar questions that I stumbled upon while looking for a solution. I feel like this would be like closing a question about some bash script giving wrong results just because you also have to work with concepts that belong to superuser.  If I asked something like "what's the kernel regularizer" then I would 100% agree

Comment: The fact that there are plenty of off-topic questions still open is only due to the fact that both the people moderating and the time & energy we can afford to devote on the task are limited; it should *not* be perceived as an indicator of what is on-topic or not - only the rules are relevant here (notice that the linked question is now closed as well for the same reason). Other than that, if you still disagree, you are very welcome to open a relevant discussion at Meta.

Comment: @desertnaut I'd say there are plenty of this questions because it's not really off topic. But thank you for your time anyway, I'm opening an account on Cross Validation and hope to get something done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numerical reasons neural networks often dont play nice with somewhat unbounded very large numbers. So just reducing the range of values for x from -50..50 to -5..5 will let your model train.

For your case you also want to remove the l2-regularizer since you cant really overfit here and definitely not have a decay of 1e-5. I gave it a go with `lr=1e-2` and `decay=lr/2`

```
Epoch 1000/1000
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1471 - val_loss: 0.1370
```

Full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from time import sleep

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu', input_shape=[1]),
                             keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu'),
                             keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu'),
                             keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation='relu'),
                             keras.layers.Dense(units=1)])

lr = 1e-2
decay = lr/2

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, decay=decay)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')

xs = np.random.random((10000, 1)) * 10 - 5
ys = xs**3 + 9*xs**2 
print(np.shape(xs))
print(np.shape(ys))

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=1000, batch_size=256, validation_split=0.2)

print(model.predict([4.0]))
```

Comment: Thank you, this did generate a steady loss decrease. I'll let the training end and come with the results

Comment: The loss decreases steadily but not enough to get an accurate result (after 10k epochs is still at 200k loss). This question is closed now, but thank you for your time anyway

Comment: @FabioR. I added the full code i used, if that still doesnt work for you id start looking at things like reinstalling packages and drivers

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to multiply my set by 10 instead of 100 while reducing the set range, now works like a charm. By the way chapeau to you for understanding this question, on Cross Validation SE it got insta-closed because "It wasn't clear enough", either you are a genius of some kind or moderators on CV have some reading comprehension issues

Comment: @FabioR. tbf the post they linked it too does include scaling your data, which is pretty similar to what i did and would have the same result^^

Comment: Yeah, but that post is as helpful as a machine learning manual and if I could find the solution just by reading a manual I wouldn't be here in the first place, at least you took time to look at my code and see what was actually wrong and you explained it to me. Also I've been studying ML for literally 3 days, most of that post is still just gibberish to me, I did read that before they linked it.  Moreover they linked to that question just because I complained, it was first closed as unclear....